# Deserializing XML with unknown fields - what will happen?

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer

We have developed an application that "talks" to Microsoft Dynamics AX using XML.
Unfortunately, the XML format isn't documented, but the guy working on the project before me simply extracted an XSD schema from the files, which we validate against when deserializing data from AX.

The only problem we have now, is that the client frequently adds new fields in AX - which naturally breaks the schema.
They want us to turn off validation altogether ("We don't want to be dependent on you every time we add a new field to try something out!"), which I have advised strongly against.

But could there really be negative consequences?
I.e., would the XmlSerializer actually mess up existing values, as long as only new values are added?
I find it pretty much impossible to test all hypothetical scenarios, which is why I'm asking here...

A concrete example would be a format like this:

```
<Root>
    <A>Foo</A>
    <B>1234</B>
</Root>
```

Suppose now they add new fields like this, but don't remove existing values:

```
<Root>
    <A>Foo</A>
    <C>9876</C>
    <B>1234</B>
    <D>Bar</D>
</Root>
```

Would we be able to parse A and B correctly nonetheless (in this or other variants)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following approach.

Define your class as follows. For each unknown field make the dictionary. Note the `XmlIgnore` attribute.

```
public class Root
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dict { get; set; }
}
```

Subscribe to `UnknownElement` event.

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
xs.UnknownElement += Xs_UnknownElement;
```

In the event handler we manually read the data from the unknown elements and put it in the dictionary.

```
private static void Xs_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    var root = (Root)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;

    if (root.Dict == null)
        root.Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    root.Dict.Add(e.Element.Name, e.Element.InnerText);
}
```

Deserialization is done as usual:

```
Root root;

using (var stream = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
    root = (Root)xs.Deserialize(stream);

Console.WriteLine(root.A);
Console.WriteLine(root.B);

foreach (var pair in root.Dict)
    Console.WriteLine(pair);
```

Comment: Thanks! We don't care about unknown elements at all. The client just wants us to ignore them. Is it still necessary to subscribe to the UnknownElement event?
And will this approach always work? What if they (unintendedly) no longer send the other (required) fields, or mix up the order? Would we be able to detect that? They send over billing data etc., so it's important that we get that over correctly in any case. Thanks!

Comment: @TravelingFox - Are you kidding me? Just ignore unknown elements. `XmlSerializer` pays no attention to them. No need subscribe to event.

Comment: Great. Even if they mess up the element order? Would be still be able to detect if elements were missing?