# How to make a property visible (scope, access modifier) only by XmlSerializer in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, scope, access-modifiers

I would like to make some property of a class visisble (scope, access modifier) only by the XML serializer.
I'm not sure about the best way to hide some properties from the consumers of a class without over engineering.

Let's see an exemple:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Version Version { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Do not used. This is a dummy property for XML serialization.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = nameof(Version))]
    public string XmlVersion
    {
        get => Version.ToString();
        set => Version = new Version(value);
    }
}
```

This kind of code allows me to use a class which is not designed to be serialized (System.Version isn't because its properties are readonly).

I would like that the consumers of my class see only Version but not the XmlVersion property.

Edit : If it's possible, I'd like those properties to be hidden even in the project where the class is so my co-worker won't use those dummy properties too.
I know I can use ObsoleteAttribute to give information why they should be avoided but those properties will still be usable which isn't the behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: Not sure this has an easy answer. Is `DataContractSerializer` an option?  Otherwise you’d be stuck with `IXmlSerializable` Or `ObsoleteAttribute`

Comment: I am not sure If I understand the question right, but I will give it a shot. Can't you just make the `XmlVersion` private instead of public?

Comment: @DavidWawrzynczyk, XmlSerializer requires a public accessor to any property to be set. It was written in a time of partially trusted assemblies – so it is quite limited. (Must also have public ctor).

Comment: Only public members are serialized by `XmlSerializer`.  See [c#: how to hide a field which is used only for XML serialization retrocompatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47571925/3744182) for confirmation and workarounds.  In fact I think this is a duplicate, agree?

Comment: Yeah, the property must be public to be serialized. I've tried internal / internal protected etc. But it throws an exception : property won't be serialized if not public. (I thought I could encapsulate those class in an assembly and keep things internal but it's not possible).
@Mitch maybe that's an option. Too bad my needs are not as easy as it should :)